# Azure Devops Yaml release pipeline: pipeline level conditional expression

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline, release

I'm trying to do something that seems pretty straightforward to me, I keep getting a not very useful mapping error when I try to run it (compile time error): "A mapping was not expected"

The error points to the line "${{ if eq(parameters.dev_vault, '001') }}:" below

Here is my yaml pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: dev_vault
    displayName: "Dev Vault Id (Same as Database Id)"
    type: string
    default: 001

...

variables:
  - template: vars/global.yml  
  - name:  devDatabaseName
    value: 
      ${{ if eq(parameters.dev_vault, '001') }}:
        "DEV_PSP"
      ${{ else }}:
        "DEV${{parameters.dev_vault}}_PSP"
...
```

Am I trying to do something that is not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
parameters:
  - name: dev_vault
    displayName: "Dev Vault Id (Same as Database Id)"
    type: string
    default: 001

...

variables:
  - template: vars/global.yml  
  - name:  devDatabaseName
    ${{ if eq(parameters.dev_vault, '001') }}:
      value: "DEV_PSP"
    ${{ else }}:
      value: "DEV${{parameters.dev_vault}}_PSP"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when it expands it will produce invalid YAML

Try:

```
    ${{ if eq(parameters.dev_vault, '001') }}:
        devDatabaseName: "DEV_PSP"
    ${{ else }}:
        devDatabaseName: "DEV${{parameters.dev_vault}}_PSP"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use this syntax because I'm also using a variable template